# How to get the ms from getDateTimeInstance

Tags: java, datetime

I want to get the date will be in  date format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:DD:MS
For example
2009-13-01 10:22:33:44

The problem that I don't succeed to get the MS

```
 public static DateFormat getFormat() {
    String systemLocale = System.getProperty("user.language"); //$NON-NLS-1$ 
    Locale locale = new Locale(systemLocale);
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
    return dateFormat;
}

String pattern = "/Date\\((\\d+)\\)/"; //$NON-NLS-1$
String updated = (strValue).replaceAll(pattern, "$1"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(updated));
        return getFormat().format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
```

I tried also to change the DateFormat to FULL and LONG and it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Use 'S' for the milliseconds.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
Date now = new Date();
System.out.println(df.format(now));
```

Prints:

```
2014-02-27 08:45:25:093
```

In your code, you can modify the `getFormat()` function:

```
public static DateFormat getFormat() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
}
```

(note that this returns a fixed date format, which is not locale-dependent anymore).

Comment: where do I need to replace the SimpleDateFormat in my code ?

Comment: Modify your `getFormat()` function to return an instance of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Not necessary, SimpleDateFormat inherits from DateFormat, @Grodriguez

Comment: @hd1: I mean replace the *implementation* to return an instance of  `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Comment: where do I need to replace the SimpleDateFormat in my code ?

Comment: return  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); from getFormat() method @user1365697

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact format, why don't you try to specify it in a format string (also it seems to me that the colon character between seconds and millis is not "very" standard)?

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS
```

Put it in an instance of `SimpleDateFormat` and here you go.

Just a note: your example does not fit your format: 13 could not be a valid month.